# How do I Query for used BETWEEN Operater for text searches in MySql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL Table in that i use `BETWEEN` Operater.

The BETWEEN Operater selects values within range. The values can be numbers, text , dates.

```
 stu_id name            city     pin
    1   Raj            Ranchi   123456
    2   sonu           Delhi    652345
    3   ANU           KOLKATA   879845
    4   K.K's Company   Delhi   345546
    5   J.K's Company   Delhi   123456
```

I have a query like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE stu_id BETWEEN 2 AND 4     //including 2 & 4

SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE name between 'A' and 'K'  //including A & not K
```

Here **My Question** is why not including K.
but I want K also in searches.

Comment: The `Between` will skip the last record of the table. So the 'K' will not included.

Comment: @SathishChelladurai why Between will skip the last record of the table?

Comment: The `BETWEEN` operator is a logical operator that allows you to specify whether a value in a range or not. You can refer about the MySQL BETWEEN here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between

Comment: @SathishChelladurai if 'A' & 'K' in range then why 'K' is not included as output?

Comment: check my answer, hope, it will works for you.

Comment: In the same way that `Between 1 and 2` will not return 2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `between` -- until you really understand it.  That is just general advice.  `BETWEEN` is inclusive, so your second query is equivalent to:

```
WHERE name >= 'A' AND
      name <= 'K'
```

Because of the equality, `'K'` *is* included in the result set.  However, names longer than one character and starting with `'K'` are not -- "Ka" for instance.

Instead, be explicit:

```
WHERE name >= 'A' AND
      name < 'L'
```

Of course, `BETWEEN` can be useful.  However, it is useful for *discrete* values, such as integers.  It is a bit dangerous with numbers with decimals, strings, and date/time values.  That is why I encourage you to express the logic as inequalities.

Comment: And here I figured between would treat those as discrete values and not even allow for more than one character, what weird behavior

Comment: @Gordon Linoff sir so what query i written so  that 'K' also in searches.

Comment: @MohitKumar I've updated the query in my answer. please check it that will include 'K' in your searches.

Comment: @MohitKumar . . . I included that query, the last example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In supplement to gordon's answer, one way to get what you're expecting is to turn your name into a discrete set of values:

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE LEFT(name, 1) between 'A' and 'K'
```

You need to appreciate that `K.K's Company` is alphabetically AFTER the letter `K` on its own so it is not BETWEEN, in the same way that 4.1 is not `BETWEEN 2 and 4`

By stripping it down to just a single character from the start of the string it will work like you expect, but take cautionary note, you should always avoid running functions on values in tables, because if you had a million names, thats a million strings that mysql has to strip out to just the first letter and it might no longer be able to use an index on name, battering the performance.

Instead, you could :

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE name >= 'A' and name < 'L'
```

which is more likely to permit the use of an index as you aren't manipulating the stored values before comparing them

This works because it asks for everything up to but not including L.. Which includes all of your names starting with K, even `kzzzzzzzz`. Numerically it is equivalent to saying `number >= 2 and number < 5` which gives you all the numbers starting with 2, 3 or 4 (like the 4.1 from before) but not the 5

Remember that BETWEEN is inclusive at both ends. Always revert to a pattern of `a >= b and a < c`, `a >= c and a < d`  when you want to specify ranges that capture all possible values

Answer (score 0):

Compare in lexicographical order, 'K.K's Company' > 'K'

Answer (score 0):

We should convert the string to integer. You can try that mysql script with CAST and SUBSTRING. I've updated your script here. It will include the last record as well.

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE name CAST(SUBSTRING(username FROM 1) AS UNSIGNED)
BETWEEN 'A' AND 'K';
```

The script will work. Hope it will helps to you.

Here I've attached my test sample.

[image]